# requests are not considered local in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration, rspec

I have the below code to provide custom error page for production environments

```
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from StandardError, :with => :render_500
end
```

When i run `rspec spec/controllers/some_controller_spec.rb` everything is fine and the value for 
`Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local` is set to true(which is the case in my config/environments/test.rb)

But when i run `rspec spec/controllers`, the configuration value is set to false and it is rendering the custom error page in my test

Why is `Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local` returned as false when i run `rspec spec/controllers` eventhough i have it set to true in my `config/environments/test.rb`?

Comment: Is the successful case really with `controller/` (singular) and the failing case with `controllers/` (plural)?

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. What i mean is, if i run one single controller spec, the configuration returns true(which is what is set in config/environments/test.rb). But when i run all the controller tests or full suite, it is returned as false